# Using Swashbuckle to Host an Existing Swagger.JSON file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an existing Swagger.json file for a .NET WebApi site which I would like to integrate with my developer site (which is at a different url) running Swashbuckle.

Can I simply copy this swagger.json file to the mvc site (content or app_data folder and do this?)

If I can, where is the best place to put it.
How do I make this the default swagger file served up by the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EnableSwagger method has two signatures, in one of them you can specify the route template to your files, so you can really serve it from wherever you want, just make sure your template matches the location of your json file. Take a look here: http://pastebin.com/MDfWNpUs